# Collocation: do + character

Tags: word-usage, collocations

> This is the character I **did** last week.

Would it be correct for an artist to use "did" in the sentence above?

She is talking about the (game) character as an assignment she finished last week.

Personally, I'd use the verb "to create"...

Comment: "Create" seems like a good word. Could you give some more context? Did she draw the character as a two-dimensional picture. Did she render it in 3D and animate it? Did the character come from her own imagination or did she realise a character designed by someone else?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK her own imagination; a two-dimensional picture.

Answer (score 1):

**Do** can stand in for an awful lot of other verbs. You might replace "character" in the quote with *web page* for a web designer, or *portrait* or *landscape* for a painter, or *article* for a journalist. What *do* stands in for depends on context. Sometimes it's there for brevity or to avoid having to think about what word to use, and sometimes it's there to avoid constructing a much more complex construction where what they did wouldn't be expressible as a single verb.

That last category applies here, I think. Without knowing the specifics, she may have conceptualised the character, done sketches, concept art, modelling, posing, animating, and if she's doing more than just the art on it, character profiling, back story, and so on. All of that can be wrapped up nicely with the verb *to do*.

Don't use it about actual people without extreme caution, as absent other context to make clear what you mean (such as someone whose job involves investigating/examining and writing reports on people), "to do **a person**" often refers to sex. Obviously that would not be the case in your example, however.